# (VB) toggle labels on/off

Tags: vb.net, toggle

I have a button that when clicked labels will show, but what code do I used to get it so when the button is clicked again they are hidden:

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label4.Hide()
        Label5.Hide()
        Label6.Hide()
    End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("All shortcuts require Shift+(Letter) combination", vbOKOnly, "Shortcuts Active")
        Label4.Show()
        Label5.Show()
        Label6.Show()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check the Visible property

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   if Label4.Visible = false then 
        MsgBox("All shortcuts require Shift+(Letter) combination", vbOKOnly, "Shortcuts Active")
        Label4.Show()
        Label5.Show()
        Label6.Show()
   else
        Label4.Hide()
        Label5.Hide()
        Label6.Hide()
   End if
End Sub
```

Or more simply read and invert the visible property

```
    Dim SetVisible = Not Label4.Visible
    if Label4.Visible = False then
        MsgBox("All shortcuts require Shift+(Letter) combination", vbOKOnly, "Shortcuts Active")
    End If
    Label4.Visible = SetVisible
    Label5.Visible = SetVisible
    Label6.Visible = SetVisible
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define a bool variable to switching on / off.
like this : when click on Button1 the variable must be true and for twice click must be false

```
dim isClicked as bool = false
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        if !isClicked then

         Label4.Show()
         Label5.Show()
         Label6.Show()
         isClicked = true

       else

         Label4.Hide()
         Label5.Hide()
         Label6.Hide()
         isClicked = false
end if
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one...

```
Private Labels As New List(Of Label)

Private Sub Form3_Shown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Labels.AddRange({Label4, Label5, Label6})
    ToggleLabelVisibility()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("All shortcuts require Shift+(Letter) combination", vbOKOnly, "Shortcuts Active")
    ToggleLabelVisibility()
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleLabelVisibility()
    For Each lbl As Label In Labels
        lbl.Visible = Not lbl.Visible
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy ..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

  Label4.Visible = not Label4.Visible
  Label5.Visible = not Label5.Visible
  Label6.Visible = not Label6.Visible

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more general function to toggle not only label, but any control

```
Private Sub Toggle(ByVal ParamArray controls() As Control)
    For Each c As Control In controls
        c.Visible = Not c.Visible
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Toggle(Label4, Label5, Label6)
End Sub
```